# MVC Core C# Get List of Cultures - 'CultureInfo' does not contain a definition for 'CultureTypes'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there anyway I can get a list of cultures eg en-US, en-UK etc? I get the following error in MVC Core 'CultureInfo' does not contain a definition for 'CultureTypes'...I'm obviously missing something here or it has changed from previous versions of MVC

```
// Get and enumerate all cultures.
allCultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);
foreach (CultureInfo ci in allCultures)
{
    // Display the name of each culture.
    Console.WriteLine("Culture: {0}", ci.Name);

    // Get the culture types of each culture. 
    combo = ci.CultureTypes;

    // Display the name of each culture type flag that is set.
    Console.Write("  ");
    foreach (CultureTypes ct in mostCultureTypes)
        if (0 != (ct & combo))
            Console.Write("{0} ", ct);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1669

Comment: Thanks Vadim. Somehow, I missed this in my search. I need to remind myself to look in github first.